# Memory use in browser (and how to increase it for test purposes)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, memory, simulate

I have a simple HTML5 demo portal consisting of 2 iframes one of which is used to launch an HTML5 game.  The other is available for customer specific stuff.

I am trying to increase the memory useage in the demo portal in order to simulate a problem a customer has where the browser crashes (I don't have access to their environment).  Running in Chrome (v30) using the timeline memory checker I get the demo portal using around 5mb on startup, dropping to 1mb-ish after a couple of seconds.  In order to up the memory useage I thought it would be as simple as adding a few img tags to my portal page, each pointing to a different 5mb image (3 in total).  I assumed this would increase the memory useage to around 20mb but it still only uses 5mb.  How can this be so.  Doesn't the browser allocate memory for the images and hold on to it?

So,

1) What am I not understanding about memory allocation in web browsers?, and

2) What's the best way to get my demo portal to use an additional 20mb more memory (without any infinite loops)?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This really isn't how to handle failures. This is a really bad approach and you need to explain what should be done when the browser craches.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to reproduce your customer's issue by artificially increasing the memory load in a different environment.

Comment: I know, I know.  But my boss wants me to do it anyway!  More in a kind of 'we can't reproduce it here even if we overload our portal, so it's your problem' kind of way.